# Conditional Comments alternative in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website that I am updating from Bootstrap 2.3.1 to 3.0.0.0

The current index.html uses quite a bit of conditional comments such as:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="font/fontello-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<![endif]-->
```

As far as I understand, conditional comments have been [depreciated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX).

So what is the current standard for such issues?  How should I be upgrading the above?

Comment: Browser support for BS3 here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I still don't understand what I am supposed to do with the above.  Is there a way to achieve the same result without using conditional comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional comments are deprecated in IE10 and up, you can still safely use them to target older versions of IE. That's by far the easiest way to do that.

And conditional comments have nothing to do with Bootstrap, that's an [IE feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment).

Comment: I see, that explains that.  Thank you very much.